# TypeError: 'FirefoxWebElement' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I would like to get URLs of Airbnb's listing pages by Python, selenium, firefox, however, my program doesn't work well.

My error code is as bellow;

```
Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pages.py", line 19, in <module>
    for links in driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@id, "listing-")]//a[contains(@href, "rooms")]'):
TypeError: 'FirefoxWebElement' object is not iterable
```

Here is my code!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

test_url = 'https://www.airbnb.jp/s/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E6%B2%96%E7%B8%84%E7%9C%8C/homes?refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&query=%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E6%B2%96%E7%B8%84%E7%9C%8C&price_min=15000&allow_override%5B%5D=&checkin=2018-07-07&checkout=2018-07-08&place_id=ChIJ51ur7mJw9TQR79H9hnJhuzU&s_tag=z4scstF7'

opts = FirefoxOptions()
opts.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=opts)
driver.get(test_url)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)

for links in driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@id, "listing-")]//a[contains(@href, "rooms")]'):
    listing_url = links.get_attribute('href')
    print(listing_url)

driver.quit()
```

I tried to change my code, another code is as bellow;
(Error message is same as my first code.)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

test_url = 'https://www.airbnb.jp/s/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E6%B2%96%E7%B8%84%E7%9C%8C/homes?refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&query=%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E6%B2%96%E7%B8%84%E7%9C%8C&price_min=15000&allow_override%5B%5D=&checkin=2018-07-07&checkout=2018-07-08&place_id=ChIJ51ur7mJw9TQR79H9hnJhuzU&s_tag=z4scstF7'

opts = FirefoxOptions()
opts.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=opts)
driver.get(test_url)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)


links = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href, "rooms")]')
for link in links:
    listing_url = link.get_attribute('href')
    print(listing_url)

driver.quit()
```

I am glad to you reply if you have a time.
Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use `find_elements_by_xpath` where return a list of `elements`

Not `find_element_by_xpath` that returned only one element

```
...
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(@id, "listing-")]//a[contains(@href, "rooms")]')
for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute('href')
    ...
```

**Output**

```
https://www.airbnb.jp/rooms/7793811?location=%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E6%B2%96%E7%B8%84%E7%9C%8C&check_in=2018-07-07&check_out=2018-07-08
https://www.airbnb.jp/rooms/7793811?location=%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E6%B2%96%E7%B8%84%E7%9C%8C&check_in=2018-07-07&check_out=2018-07-08
...
```